# How to search a text field "as is" using NEST?

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

When I index a new document like this:

```
ElasticClient.Index(product, idx => idx.Index(indexName));
```

and I try to search/query on this field (which is a 500 char text), I get no results. I want to search for something like: "687920/1" which is in this 500 char text.

Answer (score 0):

below Elasticsearch example may be useful

**delete pdm index**

```
DELETE pdm
```

**Index mapping**

```
PUT /pdm
{
  "settings":{
    "analysis":{
      "analyzer":{
    "keyword_lowercase_analyzer": {
      "type": "custom",
      "filter": ["lowercase"],
      "tokenizer": "keyword"
    }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
    "properties": {
    "product_desc": {
      "type": "string",
      "fields": {
        "raw": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
        },
        "english": {
          "type":     "text",
          "analyzer": "english"
        }
      }
    }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index document**

```
POST /pdm/product/_bulk
{ "index": { "_id": "111" }}
{ "product_desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 687920/1 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."}
{ "index": { "_id": "112" }}
{ "product_desc": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 6879210/1 It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."}
```

**search query**

```
POST /pdm/_search
{
    "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
       "product_desc": "687920/1"
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using the NEST client (I also added the NEST tag in the question). How can it be done using the NEST client?

Comment: you are use NEST as client but in back end you are use Elasticsearch if i am not wrong right. using analyzer you can get your result.